# On Lovasz theta function

Tags: graph-theory

Given a graph $G$, it is known independence number $\alpha(G)$ and Lovasz theta $\vartheta(G)$ satisfy the inequality, $\alpha(G^{\boxtimes n}) \leq \vartheta(G)^{n}$.

If $\alpha(G^{\boxtimes n}) < \vartheta(G)^{n}$, under plausible complexity theory conjectures, is it possible to have any other polynomial time computable function $\psi(G)$ that works for all graphs $G$ (or special family of graphs) and that produces numbers satisfying the inequality $\alpha(G^{\boxtimes n}) \leq \psi(G)^{n} \leq \psi(G^{\boxtimes n}) \leq \vartheta(G)^{n}$?

Comment: Yes. You could use a function that is equal to $\vartheta(G)$ except for a finite list of exceptions. I suspect you would consider this "cheating".

Comment: Yes. However this is something I would not want:) I thought I read somewhere that no other non-trivial function is possible. I do not know the reference. That is no other non trivial approximation to independence number is possible in polynomial time.

Comment: I believe no other non-trivial function is known. It may be known that no other function given by a semidefinite program is possible (this would be a fantastic result) but the tools of complexity theory are not yet capable of proving that no other polynomial-time computable function is possible.

Comment: I believe you may be able to use the reductions in [Tulsiani's paper](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~madhurt/Papers/reductions.pdf) to show that $O(1)$ levels in the Lasserre hierarchy do not provide a significant improvement over $\vartheta$ (which corresponds to the first level of Lasserre). Note that the Lasserre hierarchy relaxations are multiplicative just like $\vartheta$. And they are stronger than the Lovasz-Schrijver SDP hierarchy

Comment: @SashoNikolov This is a good reference. It says any constant $k$ rounds can be done in $n^{O(k)}$ time and still get only $\vartheta$ as optimal solution. Seems like there should be a converse that in $n^{k}$ time, one cannot do more than $O(k)$ rounds. However that sounds hard.

Comment: Bear in mind that $k$-th level Lasserre has $n^{\Omega(k)}$ variables. One way you can approach the question from your last comment is: what is the [SDP extension complexity](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.0837v3.pdf) of the projection onto the singleton variables of the $k$-th level Lasserre relaxation of the stable set polytope. SDP extension complexity lower bounds remain hard afaik, although arguably not as inaccessible as other complexity questions.

Comment: @SashoNikolov A related question. Supposing we have a better than $n^{\frac{1}{15}}$ approximation for a graph family, does that mean for that graph family we can compute clique in polynomial time?

Comment: http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse533/05au/feige-kilian-conference.pdf says approximating clique to $n^{\frac{1}{15}}$ is hard under a complexity conjecture and http://people.csail.mit.edu/madhu/papers/1994/bellare.pdf mentions a conjecture in footnote that Lovasz theta approximates clique to $n^{\frac{1}{2}}$ ($\underline{\mbox{where is this conjecture from and what progress has been made}}$?) So if the conjecture is true, lifting $15$ to $2$ should suffice showing no such function exists under complexity assumptions for general graphs.

How about for special graph families?

Comment: @JAS: It is known that approximating clique to $n^{0.9999}$ is NP-hard: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem

Comment: Oh the results I am quoting are old :(

I am also thinking since clique and Indep set are complementary, approx results should be similar for both.

Comment: That's right...

Comment: @MCH So does that somehow lead to any further info about Lovasz Theta optimality?

Comment: For one, it shows that Lovasz theta is not a good approximation unless $P=NP$.